# Forwarding traffic to another device using C++

Tags: c++, sockets

I am trialling a little project for Philips Hue and learning c++ at the same time. What I am trying to do is act a proxy between a client and the bridge. The app runs as a bridge as far as any clients are concerned, receives the request and passes this on to the bridge.

I have a weird problem where if the app runs normally, I only get a HTTP 200 OK response, nothing else, if I step through the code, I get the full response.

Below is my code, there is no thread, there are no classes, its all being done in the main method.

```
WindowsSocket socketManager(&bitsLibrary);


    if (!socketManager.createSocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP, 80, 1024))
    {
        cout << "Failed to create socket" << endl;
    }

    socketManager.bindAndStartListening();

    WindowsSocket bridgeSocketManager(&bitsLibrary);



    while (true)
    {

        sockaddr_in clientAddr;
        memset(&clientAddr, 0, sizeof(sockaddr_in));
        SOCKET clientSocket = socketManager.acceptClientAndReturnSocket(&clientAddr);
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
        string received = socketManager.receiveDataOnSocket(&clientSocket);
        bitsLibrary.writeToLog(received);

        struct sockaddr_in server;
        server.sin_family = AF_INET;
        //server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("139.162.223.149");
        server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.67");
        server.sin_port = htons(80);
        bridgeSocketManager.createSocket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
        int result = connect(*bridgeSocketManager.returnSocket(), (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
        if (result < 0)
        {
            cout << "Connect Failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));

        SOCKET * bridgeSocket = bridgeSocketManager.returnSocket();
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
        socketManager.sendToSocket(bridgeSocket, received);
        string reply = socketManager.receiveDataOnSocket(bridgeSocket);

        //boost::replace_all(reply, "Host: 192.168.1.70", "Host: 192.168.1.67");
        bitsLibrary.writeToLog(reply);
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(1000));
        int sent = socketManager.sendToSocket(&clientSocket, reply);
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
        bridgeSocketManager.closeSocket();
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
        socketManager.closeSocket(&clientSocket);
        /*while (true)
        {
            SOCKET clientSocket = socketManager.acceptClientAndReturnSocket(&clientAddr);
            SocketProcessor socketProcessor;
            socketProcessor.startThread(socketManager, clientSocket);
        }*/
    }
    socketManager.closeSocket();
```

My socket receive method is as follows:

```
std::string WindowsSocket::receiveDataOnSocket(SOCKET *socket)
{
    if (*socket != -1)
    {
        string receivedData = "";
        char *temp = NULL;
        int bytesReceived = 0;
        do
        {
            bytesReceived = recv(*socket, this->buffer, this->bufferLength, 0);
            if (bytesReceived == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                string socketError = this->getErrorStringFromErrorCode(WSAGetLastError()).c_str();

                stringstream logstream;
                logstream << "Failed to receive data on socket.The socket will now be closed and cleanup performed. Error: " << socketError;

                this->bitsLibrary->writeToLog(logstream.str(), "WindowsSocket", "receiveDataOnSocket");
                closesocket(*socket);
                WSACleanup();
                throw SocketException(socketError.c_str());
                return "";
            }

            //If we got here, then we should be able to get some data
            temp = new char[bytesReceived + 1];
            //memset(&temp, 0, bytesReceived + 1);
            strncpy(temp, this->buffer, bytesReceived);
            temp[bytesReceived] = '\0'; //Add a null terminator to the end of the string
            receivedData.append(temp);
            temp = NULL;

            //Now clear the buffer ready for more data
            memset(this->buffer, 0, this->bufferLength);
            cout << "Bytes Received: " << bytesReceived << " BUffer Length: " << this->bufferLength << endl;
        } while (bytesReceived == this->bufferLength && bytesReceived >= 0); //Keep going until the received bytes is less than the buffer length

        return receivedData;
    }
    else
    {
        stringstream logstream;
        logstream << "Can't receive on socket as already be closed";
        throw SocketException(logstream.str().c_str());
    }
}
```

The send method looks as follows:

```
int WindowsSocket::sendToSocket(SOCKET *clientSocket, string dataToSend)
{
    //dataToSend.append("\r\n");
    int sentBytes = send(*clientSocket, dataToSend.c_str(), dataToSend.length(), 0);
    if (sentBytes == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        throw SocketException(this->getErrorStringFromErrorCode(WSAGetLastError()).c_str());
    }
    return sentBytes;
}
```

When I run the app normally in Visual Studio with no break points, I get the following output:

```
03/02/2017 22:08:16:    WindowsSocket/bindAndStartListening:    Socket has binded and is now listening
Bytes Received: 413 BUffer Length: 1024
Receiving data
GET /api/nouser/config HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.70
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8

03/02/2017 22:08:22:    BaseSocket/createSocket:        Creating buffer of length 1024
Bytes Received: 17 BUffer Length: 1024
03/02/2017 22:08:23:    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Sent: 17
```

If I set a breakpoint and then step through the code I get the following:

```
03/02/2017 22:09:03:    WindowsSocket/bindAndStartListening:    Socket has binded and is now listening
Bytes Received: 413 BUffer Length: 1024
GET /api/nouser/config HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.70
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.8

03/02/2017 22:09:09:    BaseSocket/createSocket:        Creating buffer of length 1024
Bytes Received: 630 BUffer Length: 1024
03/02/2017 22:09:17:    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 1 Aug 2011 09:00:00 GMT
Connection: close
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Content-type: application/json

{"name":"Philips hue","datastoreversion":"59","swversion":"01036659","apiversion":"1.16.0","mac":"00:17:88:1a:1f:43","bridgeid":"001788FFFE1A1F43","factorynew":false,"replacesbridgeid":null,"modelid":"BSB001"}
Sent: 630
```

Notice when I don't do a break point I receive only 17 bytes of the HTTP 200 OK but when I breakpoint and step through the code I then get over 600 bytes and receive everything that I was expecting.

I can't see what the problem is, I've put sleeps in expecting this would "fix" the issue but even the sleeps make no difference.

Comment: your condition of (bytesReceived == this->bufferLength) is nonsensical

Comment: Read much more about [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), which is more complex than what you imagine. Consider using some HTTP server or HTTP client libraries. Look into [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) (HTTP client) & [libonion](http://coralbits.com/libonion/) (HTTP server). See also [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/), [Boost](http://boost.org/), and [Qt](http://qt.io/) frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

send()/recv() are low-level calls to work with sockets. To properly handle HTTP, which is quite a complex protocol, you should be aware of HTTP specification, see about-to-become-obsolete [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).

Your best bet is to set condition in do-while loop of receiveDataOnSocket() to while (bytesReceived > 0). It will only work, if server closes connection after sending the response.

If persistent connection is used, then the next best thing you can do is to use non-blocking sockets (at least for accepting data from both client and server) and as data arrives, forward them to other side. It may work, but may also fail.

The next thing is actually implementing HTTP, which is too complex for C++ tutorial.

Comment: I put bytesReceived == bufferLength as I expected if there was more data the buffer would always fill so then if I had less then the buffer I knew I had everything and could break from the loop. If I just say bytesReceived > 0 it goes back to the recv method and hangs waiting for more data when there isn't any, so how could I get round that

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that, didn't realise HTTP was any more complex than just reading from a socket and chucking straight out to another socket.

Comment: From what I've seen, what I'm doing should work, just receiving the data from one socket and chucking out to another, this was also kind of proved by stepping through the code so I was obviously adding a delay, I then get the full response from the forwarded to device. I've done a test where I've put a 10ms sleep just before the recv function and now it works perfectly fine.